# Positioning Trending View Widget CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to position my widget. It positions correctly on local host. However, when I upload to file server the position is over rided and not using my position.

I just want to be able to move the widget. Any styling is not working

https://www.tradingview.com/widget/

code

```
<div class="chart">
    <!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
    <span  id="tradingview-copyright"><a ref="nofollow noopener" target="_blank" href="http://www.tradingview.com" style="color: rgb(173, 174, 176); font-family: &quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">Market Movers by <span style="color: #3BB3E4">TradingView</span></a></span>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-hotlists.js">
        {
            "exchange": "US",
            "showChart": true,
            "locale": "en",
            "width": "400",
            "height": "600",
            "plotLineColorGrowing": "rgba(60, 188, 152, 1)",
            "plotLineColorFalling": "rgba(255, 74, 104, 1)",
            "gridLineColor": "rgba(242, 242, 242, 1)",
            "scaleFontColor": "rgba(218, 221, 224, 1)",
            "belowLineFillColorGrowing": "rgba(60, 188, 152, 0.05)",
            "belowLineFillColorFalling": "rgba(255, 74, 104, 0.05)",
            "symbolActiveColor": "rgba(242, 250, 254, 1)"
        }
    </script>
```

css

```
.chart {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 700px 450px 0 0;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;

}
```

Comment: We can't possibly know how your widget *should* be positioned without you telling us, or showing the supporting code that is causing the problem. Please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), clearly showing the problem. What I can say is that a fixed `margin` that high won't work on any sort of mobile device, and that the problem is going to be in where you are inserting the `<div class="chart">` element onto the page. If it's inside a container, you'll need different styling.

Comment: I dont care about the position i just want to be able to move it. Nothing is working.

Comment: what styling would i need?

Comment: I just said; we can't possibly know unless you showcase your HTML that surrounds the `<div class="chart">` element, along with the CSS that supports it... and also state **how** you want to position it.

Comment: What look at the link and how im getting the widget.

Comment: the position i want is in the css code. The widget is displaying in the top left corner and wont move.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to move the container you have to move the right container, but you are moving the wrong one. Just analyse the output code with the debugging console to understand what I mean. See this example for positioning the container to a different position:

```css
.chart + div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart">
    <!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
    <span  id="tradingview-copyright"><a ref="nofollow noopener" target="_blank" href="http://www.tradingview.com" style="color: rgb(173, 174, 176); font-family: &quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">Market Movers by <span style="color: #3BB3E4">TradingView</span></a></span>

</div>

<script src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-hotlists.js">
    {
        "exchange": "US",
        "showChart": true,
        "locale": "en",
        "width": "400",
        "height": "600",
        "plotLineColorGrowing": "rgba(60, 188, 152, 1)",
        "plotLineColorFalling": "rgba(255, 74, 104, 1)",
        "gridLineColor": "rgba(242, 242, 242, 1)",
        "scaleFontColor": "rgba(218, 221, 224, 1)",
        "belowLineFillColorGrowing": "rgba(60, 188, 152, 0.05)",
        "belowLineFillColorFalling": "rgba(255, 74, 104, 0.05)",
        "symbolActiveColor": "rgba(242, 250, 254, 1)"
    }
</script>
```